# Struggling with a statistics-inspired optimization problem with two variables

Tags: statistics, optimization

Suppose you want to test whether two sets of measurements are coming from the same population or two different populations (e.g., you want to see if two brands of tires have equal durability). That is, you are testing whether you can reject the null hypothesis that $\mu_x-\mu_y= 0$.

You test $n_x$ tires from one brand and $n_y$ tires from the other. The variance of the difference of the sample means $\sigma^2_{\bar{x}-\bar{y}} $ $=\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} +\frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  $, has a minimum value when $n_x = n_y$, provided that $\sigma_x=\sigma_y$. It is desirable to keep the variance $\sigma^2_{\bar{x}-\bar{y}} $ at a minimum, because it results in a narrower confidence interval.

Now suppose that it is known that $\sigma^2_x>\sigma^2_y$. What is the optimal ratio of $n_x$ and $n_y$ that guarantees that the variance $\sigma^2_{\bar{x}-\bar{y}} $$=\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} +\frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  $ will have a minimum value?

I tried setting to zero the partial derivative of the expression with respect to $n_x$ and $n_y$, but I got out a complicated expression that I could not simplify to anything meaningful.

Comment: Surely the variance is minimised only for $n_x,n_y\to\infty$. Do you have a constraint that $n_x+n_y$ is fixed?

Comment: That's true. But suppose they sum to a finite value, n. What is the optimum ratio of nx to ny that would yield the smallest variance under that constraint?